# Accesing Base Class Signal using derived Class Object Qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals

Hi I am new to the Qt and C++. I have one requirement where I have to access signal of Base class using derived class object. Whether is it possible and if yes then how? I tried to implement it using one simple application, but it is not working.

//Base Class

//Which is emitting signal temp() in it's constructor

```
class IPCBase : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit IPCBase(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~IPCBase();

signals:
    void temp();

private:
    Ui::IPCBase *ui;
};
```

//cpp

```
IPCBase::IPCBase(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::IPCBase)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug()<<"coming to base cpp";
    emit temp();
}
```

I have created one derived class named IPCReceiver and using the object of IPCReceiver(derived class) I am trying to use the connect statement in another class(Form) and call the SLOT.It is not giving compilation error but the SLOT is not getting called.

```
Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    IPCReceiver *receiver = new IPCReceiver;

    connect(receiver, SIGNAL(temp()), this, SLOT(debug()));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When `IPCReceiver` emits its `temp` signal?

Answer (score 3):

Your signal `temp()` emits in constructor of a class. That's why your connection is unusable. In your logic: at first emits signal in constructor, then you create connection. You must emit signal **after** creation of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You generally shouldn't be emitting any signals from constructors of any class deriving from `QObject` as it makes the class much harder to use. You need to emit the signal from the event loop, after the constructor has finished. There  are at least two idioms that express that:

#### Using a Connection to `QObject::destroyed`

```
IPCBase::IPCBase(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::IPCBase)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject src;
    connect(&src, &QObject::destroyed, this, &IPCBase::temp, Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
```

The `src` object is used only as a source of a generic signal.

#### Using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`

```
IPCBase::IPCBase(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::IPCBase)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "temp", Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
```

As an aside, you don't need to allocate Ui dynamically, you can make it a member variable instead; then the compiler-generated default destructor is sufficient.